# ".cpp" files in project include path would not be seen by the project

Tags: c++, cmake, include

Say I have a simple project Test. Here is the CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(Test)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

include_directories(path/to/somewhere)

add_executable(Test main.cpp)
```

Now, in the include directory I have `A.h` and `A.cpp`. Whenever I compile, I always get undefined reference to the definition of the functions declared in `A.h`. It is clear that the project is not seeing `A.cpp` at all.

May I please know how do I make it work? Given that I prefer not doing `add_executable(Test main.cpp A.cpp)` since I think `A` should rather be a separate thing than integrated into the executable directly. Is my only option building `A` into a`.so`? Can I somehow modify the cmake to work around building library?

Comment: Do you want `A.cpp` to be compiled as a dynamic library instead of linked with `main.cpp`? This will reduce the size of your final `Test` executable, but it will still access an external library. Doing `add_executable(Test main.cpp A.cpp)` is the normal way, especially for small programs.

Comment: _"I think A should rather be a separate thing than integrated into the executable directly"_ -- what sort of separate thing are you looking for? (What option besides a shared library (.so) is there?) Why should it be separate? Your executable apparently needs something from `A`, so why not link everything together into one thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> “.cpp” files in project include path would not be seen by the project

Your problem is not about what the project "sees". The problem is that you failed to link with the translation unit.

> Is my only option building A into a.so?

No, you don't need to build a shared library. You can use a static or "object" library instead.

Or you can list the source file in the add_executable directive.